# Example of infinite abelian group having exactly $n$ elements of finite order.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

**Question**: does there exist an infinite abelian group having exactly $n$ elements of finite order?

**My attempt**: **yes**! consider the most familiar, infinite abelian group $\mathbb{Z}$ (of course with respect to $+$) and consider the additive group of integers modulo $n$ that is, $\mathbb{Z_n}$. Now consider, $G=\mathbb{Z} ×\mathbb{Z_n}$, then clearly, $G$ is infinite abelian group (since both $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z_n}$ are abelian).

Further, as $\mathbb{Z}$ has exactly one element of finite order (which is identity $0$) it follows that the group $G$ has exactly $n$ elements of finite order and they are, $(0,0), (0,1),...,(0,n-1)$. **Am I correct?**

**'Can we have more interesting examples like this'**?

Comment: To turn this into a rigorous proof, you should determine the order of an arbitrary element $(i,j)$ of $\mathbb{Z}\times (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$. As for more interesting examples, are you familiar with semi-direct products? You could, for example, take a semi-direct product $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})\rtimes \mathbb{Z}$, with $\mathbb{Z}$ acting as some cyclic subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) \cong (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$. And of course if $n$ is composite, then you don't have to take cyclic groups, you can do similar constructions with other groups of order $n$.

Comment: And you can replace $\mathbb{Z}$ by other torsion-free groups.

Comment: @AlexB Sir, thanks for replying, but isn't the above proof is sufficient? Further arbitrary element of $\mathbb{Z}×\mathbb{Z_n}$ need Not be of finite order!! Only those element which I had listed are of finite order. For eg: $(2,1)$ in $G$ is of infinite order!

Comment: Well, that last claim is exactly what you need to prove.